# Does having non-ECC SDRAM affect security of the system?

Tags: ssh, memory

If I don't have [SECDED ECC DRAM](http://cr.yp.to/hardware/ecc.html), is it possible or realistic that a bit could flip around `sshd`, and grant a lucky lurker access to my system without requiring a valid password?

Answer (score 3):

It is *possible*.  It is stupendously, fantastically, indescribably *improbable*.

It will never happen.  It is not realistic.  Monkeys will type Shakespeare before it happens.  Daenerys Targaryen will bear a living child before it happens.  If two Wednesdays come together in a week... it'll happen long, long, **long** after that.

---

And as @Forest points out... It happened anyway, with [Rowhammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_hammer) (and even to ECC with the [ECCploit](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2018/11/potentially-disastrous-rowhammer-bitflips-can-bypass-ecc-protections/) variant).  Say Hello to the Wednesdays!

Comment: And then rowhammer happened.